# `maven compile` can not find package when they are installed in ~/.m2

Tags: maven

I am trying to learn how to build a maven project.
this is my `./src/main/java/Hello.java`

```java
import com.google.code.gson.*;

public class Hello{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
  }
}
```

This file does't do something actually, I just want to learn how to import a 3rd library.
this is my `./pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

So, I try to execute `mvn compile`.

But there is an error:

```
package com.google.code.gson does not exist
```

But in my `~/.m2/repository`

```sh
$ tree -L 3 ~/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson
/Users/apple/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson
├── 2.8.5
│   ├── gson-2.8.5.jar.lastUpdated
│   └── gson-2.8.5.pom.lastUpdated
├── gson
│   └── 2.8.5
│       ├── _remote.repositories
│       ├── gson-2.8.5.jar
│       ├── gson-2.8.5.jar.sha1
│       ├── gson-2.8.5.pom
│       └── gson-2.8.5.pom.sha1
```

I seems that mvn don't add `~/.m2/repository` to my classpath, How to fix this?

```sh
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-25T02:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: /Users/apple/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.0
Java version: 10, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to GSON [javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5) , there is no package called `com.google.code.gson.*`. The root package starts from `com.google.gson` . So change to :

```
import com.google.gson.*;
```

What you see in the `<groupId>` has nothing to do with the package name. Always refer to the [javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5) or its [source codes](https://github.com/google/gson/tree/master/gson/src/main/java) for the package name.